# set text echo next to image

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page here with some text in an echo and 1 image, the image is at the top left now but the text is underneath the image. how di i make it so the text is next to the image?

i tried editing the text using css but the text wont move.

```css
.mouse {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
  <title>page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="mouse" src="mouse.jpg" alt="mouse">
  <?php
        echo "Vestibulum maximus nisl vel est sodales, ut fringilla magna ultrices. Nam mi augue, tristique non interdum id, maximus id nisi. Aenean finibus mollis felis vitae pulvinar. Aenean ut vestibulum tellus. Curabitur quis dui turpis. Nunc a luctus nunc. Sed massa neque, consequat sit amet facilisis non, hendrerit at quam. Integer condimentum quam id libero imperdiet, sodales mattis dui aliquam. Fusce tempus ipsum eros, non mattis eros mollis non. Praesent malesuada eros id lorem scelerisque, non commodo purus condimentum. Mauris vitae volutpat lacus. Pellentesque iaculis, purus non bibendum suscipit, nisl est consectetur ligula, mattis pharetra tortor purus a leo. Sed sed luctus nulla. Cras aliquet nisi bibendum sapien efficitur, congue efficitur nunc luctus."
       ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your image display is set to 'inline-block', otherwise nothing can be in the same line.

Comment: The text is not wrapped into any additional element here, so the image and it should start on the same line. If they don’t, then this must be due to your CSS, which you failed to show us. Please go read [mre].

Comment: I added the css, but i already have the inline block on the image but it wont move

Comment: With that, the text would not be “under the image”, the first line is still next to it - https://jsfiddle.net/onmdu50p/ If you want the text to break into _multiple_ lines next to the image - then either float the image, or add more markup to create a proper column layout (depending on what exactly you want.)

Comment: Am I missing something? The code snippet does not work.